# Angular 4 with scroll pagination and sorting

Tags: angular

I am working with Angular 4 and I am new to this.
I want to show a table(grid) with scroll pagination and sorting options.

Is there any component available for to achieve this?

Comment: smart table search on google you will get it

Comment: view angularjs website and go to the smart tables

Comment: Use angular material table

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery Datatable in Angular 2/4 just you have to do two things.
Just Add these two line in your .Ts file just below the Import Section.

```
declare var jquery: any;
declare var $: any;
```

then write down a function as same with your table Id your Datatable will render.

```
   ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
        $('#Data').dataTable();
    }
```

it works no issues at all.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the input, Datatable provides numbers pagination, can we change it to scroll pagination?

Comment: No You cannot do that u have to use  diffrent Datatable object for that .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about components but you can certainly try Angular DataTables.

As defined by the creator :
" Angular Structural framework for dynamic web apps +   DataTables jQuery plug-in for complex HTML tables".

Link : https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome

The installation instructions are well defined and works very well straight of the bat. Once the installation is complete you can use it in your desired component class.

Example : https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/angular-way